# How to check either both properties or none of them are present in configuration element?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, configurationelement

Is there way to write some `ConfigurationValidatorAttribute` or in some other way that will allow either both `Prop1` and `Prop2` are present or none of them?

**EDITED**

In the following config file when I'll try to get `Domains` I want to get **runtime** exception because `domain3` element must have both `Prop1` and `Prop2` or none of them, but not only one of them!

Just like `IsRequired` is checked in runtime and throws error if the element doesn't has `Name` attribute.

```
<MySection>
        <Domains>
          <Domain Name="domain1" Prop1="1" Prop2="4" /> 
          <Domain Name="domain2" /> 
          <Domain Name="domain3" Prop1="1" /> 
        </Domains>         
    </MySection>

public class ConfigElement : ConfigurationElement
{     
    [ConfigurationProperty("Name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["Name"]; }
        set { this["Name"] = value; }
    }        

    [ConfigurationProperty("Prop1")]
    public int Prop1
    {
        get { return (int)this["Prop1"]; }
        set { this["Prop1"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("Prop2")]
    public int Prop2
    {
        get { return (int)this["Prop2"]; }
        set { this["Prop2"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the behaviour that you would want if this validation failed?  Runtime exception?

Comment: I don't think you can get a compilation error since the app.config can always be changed at a later stage. But you can add xsd validation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334473/providing-intellisense-xsd-validation-to-configsections.

Comment: @dtryon, I edited my post. Yes I want runtime exception similar to as `IsRequeired`, for example, throws excetpion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the [PostDeserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.postdeserialize.aspx) of [ConfigurationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyx77cz3) in your `ConfigElement` Class

```
 protected override void PostDeserialize()
        {
            base.PostDeserialize();
            //Do what you want
        }
```

There is a good example [on this blog post](http://blog.rjcox.co.uk/2010/05/23/custom-configuration-3/).

Comment: This, coupled with ElementInformation.IsPresent is also useful if you want your "It's not there default" to differ from your "It's there default".